# Associate one variable to multiple variables in R

Tags: r, associations, chi-squared, contingency

I'm still working on my project in R.
My questionnaire's database consists of 39 variables, each of it with 20 Nominal responses. I'm creating 2 x 2 contingency tables for all the variables and, because the low sample number, willing to apply Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data.

Now, I'm trying to associate variable number 1 to the other 38. Then, Variable number 2 to the other 37, and so on.

I can do the contingency tables and Fisher's Exact Test for each, just like in the next code, but it's getting kinda monotonous.

```
Who_answers.age <- table(BD$Who_answers,BD$age, dnn = c("Who_answers","age"))
FT.Who_answers.age<-fisher.test(x = Who_answers.age, alternative = "two.sided")
FT.Who_answers.age$p.value

Who_answers.gender <- table(BD$Who_answers,BD$gender, dnn = c("Who_answers","gender"))
FT.Who_answers.gender<-fisher.test(x = Who_answers.gender, alternative = "two.sided")
FT.Who_answers.gender$p.value

Who_answers.diagnosis <- table(BD$Who_answers,BD$diagnosis, dnn = c("Who_answers","diagnosis"))
FT.Who_answers.diagnosis<-fisher.test(x = Who_answers.diagnosis, alternative = "two.sided")
FT.Who_answers.diagnosis$p.value

Who_answers.acomp_rutsu <- table(BD$Who_answers,BD$acomp_rutsu, dnn = c("Who_answers","acomp_rutsu"))
FT.Who_answers.acomp_rutsu<-fisher.test(x = Who_answers.acomp_rutsu, alternative = "two.sided")
FT.Who_answers.acomp_rutsu$p.value

Who_answers.Cuarto_propio <- table(BD$Who_answers,BD$Cuarto_propio, dnn = c("Who_answers","Cuarto_propio"))
FT.Who_answers.Cuarto_propio<-fisher.test(x = Who_answers.Cuarto_propio, alternative = "two.sided")
FT.Who_answers.Cuarto_propio$p.value

Who_answers.Duerme_con <- table(BD$Who_answers,BD$Duerme_con, dnn = c("Who_answers","Duerme_con"))
FT.Who_answers.Duerme_con<-fisher.test(x = Who_answers.Duerme_con, alternative = "two.sided")
FT.Who_answers.Duerme_con$p.value
```

Is there a way to code all those associations and their Fisher's Exact Test more easily?

As mentioned in my previous questions, I'm fairly new to R. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Your use of terminology confused me. By “nominal” did you mean binomial?  Also, it would appear that you have not taken any steps to prepare for the serious multiple comparisons problem that this strategy creates.

Comment: Yes, IRTFM, I mean dichotomous variables (Yes-No). 
Also, what do you mean by "you have not taken any steps to prepare for the serious multiple comparisons problem that this strategy creates"?

Comment: IRTFM is referring to this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem  one way to deal with that is: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction

Comment: I think the terms to be searching on might be “multiple item response theory”. After all you have. 10 cases and 37 questions.

Comment: I think the terms to be searching on might be “multiple item response theory”. After all you have 10 cases and 37 questions. And even if the number of questions didn’t outnumber  the number of subjects, there would still seem to be a serious issue with lack of independence.

Answer (score 0):

a purely technical answer; avoiding the issue of whether you should do this.

```
to_do_list <- c("age","gender","diagnosis") # extend as needed

(pval_results <- lapply(to_do_list,\(x){
  fisher.test(x =  table(BD$Who_answers,BD[[x]]),
                                  alternative = "two.sided")$p.value
}) |> setNames(to_do_list))
```